# Is there a missing *in* in the sentence "*Tanks are legal to own the USA and other countries*"?

Tags: prepositions

In the following paragraph, is there a missing *in* in the sentence "*Tanks are legal to own the USA and other countries*"?

> Who can own a tank?
>
> Tanks are legal to own the USA and other countries. There are no US Federal restrictions to owning a tank with a demilitarized (disabled) main gun. You may operate it on private land without restrictions. You will also need to determine if there are State or local laws prohibiting tank ownership. If you can own a tractor, you can own a tank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Otherwise, one might assume that tanks can have possession over countries, which is a bit weird for an object.

Comment: Thank you! I have the same feeling just as you described. I asked this question just for confirmation. The quotes are from this website: https://www.drivetanks.com/own-one/

Comment: It was probably just something that the write didn't notice while writing, as that English level sounds like native.